# Author name-surname mistake in the Google Scholar citation

Tags: citations, code, personal-name

I have a problem with the appearance of my paper in Google Scholar.

My name is correctly represented in the journal artical as "Nilhan Kaya," so the citation should be "Kaya, N". However, Google Scholar has my name and surname switched and my surname's letters treated as initials: "Nilhan, K. A. Y. A.".

Is there a way I can fix this or somewhere I can send an email? I clicked on google scholar help center web site but it didn't open (404, you cannot reach this web site).

Comment: Unclear - is the mistake in the actual journal article or in Google's scraping of the data? As an unpaid service, Google Scholar has no particular incentive to get everything right.

Comment: At the actual journal article, citation is right but at google scholar citation is unfortunately wrong.

Comment: So the article used 'Kaya, N' which Google somehow converted to 'Nihilan, K.A.Y.A'? Interesting, that would suggest Google is somehow linking the article to some other listing...

Comment: Yes the article used "Kaya, N." and google scholar converted "Nilhan, K. A. Y. A". It is really interesting because neither the name and surname arrangement is true nor the surname typing is true. I contacted with this article's journal but they said, our citation is right, google scholar had a mistake so you should contact with google scholar.

Comment: @NilhanKaya I think all we can do is give the same advice as the journal: this is an issue with Google Scholar. The actual citation is the one that matches the paper, and anyone citing your paper should be reading your paper and using those details, not the ones on Google Scholar. You can complain to Google, maybe they'll fix it or maybe they won't care.

Comment: Just register your profile with google scholar and remove the wrong citation associated with your name. Notice, very often you have more than one sources (e.g. from preprints) of your paper, you will not suffer by removing the wrong one.